# $C([0,1])$ not a closed subset of $L^{1}[0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$C([0,1])$ is not a closed subset of $L^1([0,1])$ with $L^1$ norm.

Does this counter example work ?

$f_n(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      n &x\in(0,\frac{1}{n^2}) \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} &x\in (\frac{1}{n^2},1) \\
   \end{cases}
$

This converges to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, This  function is Lebesgue integrable but not continuous.

Can I safely say that $C^n[0,1]$ for $0\leq n \leq \infty$ is not closed in $L^1[0,1]$ ?

Comment: I don't see how $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is not continuous on $[0, 1]$.

Comment: Take $\epsilon =\delta =1$ and we see that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}>1$ or simply observe that the function blows up at $0$.

Comment: @lisyarus Because it is not bounded. Continuous almost everywhere is not the same as being almost everywhere equal to a continuous function.

Comment: You may want to cite the particular convergence theorem you use: you have to show convergence in the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Oh, my! I missed the "one divided by" part somehow! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works. You may want to use $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left\lvert x-\frac12\right\rvert}}$, but it is essentially the same. An analytic example is $f_n(x)=\frac{(2x)^n}{1+(2x)^n}$, which is dominated by the constant $1$ and converges pointwise (and thus in $L^1$) to the integrable function $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }x<\frac12\\ \frac12&\text{if }x=\frac12\\ 1&\text{if }x>\frac12\end{cases}.$$

The latter is not almost-everywhere equal to any continuous function.

Comment: can you provide an hint for construction a non-trivial closed subset for the above space!

Comment: @panchal Are $\ker$-s of continuous linear functionals trivial?

Comment: sure they are non-trivial but I hope to find a different one !

Comment: @PanchalShamsundar You can consider a family $\mathcal F\subseteq L^\infty[0,1]$ and the subspace $$\left\{ f\in L^1\,:\, \forall h\in F,\ \int_0^1 fh\,dx=0\right\}$$ This should really cover all of them, by Riesz representation theorem.